# difference between domain and connected subspace

Tags: general-topology

hi i found in Philippe Souplet book "$\Omega$ is domain " so what is the  difference between the following notations : domain , connected subspace and bounded domain and  another question domain is  always connected?
thanks

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(mathematical_analysis)) for a somewhat general discussion of the term, which may or may not be relevant to your textbook.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio thanks i understand that a domain is open connected subset but if i assumed that i have a regular bounded subset can i say that is connected?

Comment: "Bounded", "open", and "connected" are logically independent conditions. That is, for each of the eight ways of assigning "true/false" to each attribute, there exists a subset having precisely the flagged properties.